# I cant switch Environment to make migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I try to make migration with Entity Framework in host database. But I wont to change environent from localhost. I tryed dotnet run --environment Production, but it returns environment Development. I changed "ConnectionStrings" in appsettings.json, but I see it`s not right way

Comment: "make migration"? What do you mean? Create a new migration, or apply migrations to a database?

Comment: Both, I guess. As I see then I create migration, it also work wit local db